# WPF Net3.5 WebBrowser HTMLElement Mouse Click

Tags: html, wpf, browser

Ive been using a WIndowsFormHost to host a Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control and adding a event handler to fire when the mouse is clicked on a HTML element inside the control

```
((System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)sender).Document.Click -= new System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventHandler(htmlElementClick);
```

This works well.

I want to do the same in a native .Net3.5 WebBrowser control, how?

I can get the HTML document by casing

```
var doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)myWebBrowser.Document;
```

and using doc to access the HTML contencts.

But how do I handle a mouse cick on an Element inside the HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but this should work:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument dom = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)myBrowser.Document;

((mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents_Event)(dom)).onclick += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents_onclickEventHandler(DocumentClickHandler);

private static bool DocumentClickHandler()
{
    // Do your stuff here

    return true;
}
```